# C++ - Hash table with function pointers

Tags: c++, function-pointers

This is my first post on this website. I'm on a project where I code a hashtable in C++. I have a problem with function pointers.

I have a hashtable that contains some students (identified by their student's number). I must use function pointers to pass hash in parameter.

My code is under:

```
//file main.cpp
Table t1;
unsigned int(Table::* ptrHash)(unsigned int);
ptrHash = &Table::hash;
t1.insertStudent(11507461, 20, ptrHash);

// file Table.cpp
void Table::insertStudent(unsigned int numberStudent, unsigned int (*f)(unsigned int)) {...}
unsigned int Table::hash(unsigned int cleEtu) {...}

//file Table.h
void insertStudent(unsigned int numberStudent, unsigned int (*f)(unsigned int));
unsigned int hash(unsigned int numberStudent);
```

My prompt gives me this error:

```
no matching function for call to 'Table::insertStudent(int, unsigned int (Table::*&)(unsigned int))' t1.insererEtu(11507461, 20, ptrHachage); 
note:no known conversion for argument 3 from ‘unsigned int (Table::*)(unsigned int)’ to ‘unsigned int (*)(unsigned int)’
```

I understand that it's not the same for it but I don't know how to solve it. I try a lot of ways but none have work.

It will save me if someone can help me!

Comment: Member function pointer types are different than regular pointer types. This is why you see `Table::*` and not just `(*)`. Either find a way to wrap the member function so it's a non-member function pointer, or better yet make the hash table just use member function pointers.

Comment: Define your hashing function as a free function instead of as a member function. (The point of passing a function pointer is that the function can be independent from the hash table.) It would make more sense to pass the function pointer to the constructor, though – using different hashing functions for each insertion will go wrong.

Comment: Please work on providing a [mcve], too, otherwise this question has a good chance of being closed.

Comment: _I must use function pointers_ Why?

Comment: If `hash` and `insertStudent` are members of the same class, why do you need to pass a pointer in the first place? Can't you just have one function call the other one?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I will try to make a hash function not in my class Table. I must use function pointers because my teacher wants.

Answer (score 2):

The cause of your problem is that there is a difference between pointers to normal functions and pointers to member functions. The function `insertStudent` takes a pointer to a normal function but you call it with a pointer to a member function from the `Table` class.

Personally I would not use function pointers at all in this case, I would make
`insertStudent` parameterized on the hash-function. This will allow the hash function to be any object that has a function-call operator that accepts an `int` and returns an `int`.

If my teacher was forcing me to use function pointers I would make the hash function a static member function of the `Table` class, to keep it close. There is a fundamental difference between static and non-static member functions. Static member functions are not called on a specific object and are therefore closer related to normal functions.

Comment: So how would you make it work?  I think this answer could be fleshed out with suggestions to lambdas and std::bind.

Comment: Actually, the hash function should not be an argument to `insertStudent()` in any way. It should be an argument to the table's constructor. Whether by function argument, template argument, or virtual inheritance does not really matter. But it's nothing that should be changeable on an element-by-element basis.

Comment: I have discussed with my classmates and they have use the hash function in the main (so not like a member function of Table). I will try this way. Thanks a lot for your answers!